# Update number value with a max in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to update a numeric field with a maximun number in oracle.

For example, if the number maximun is 10 and in the update is 11, the number update is 10.

```
DATA SOURCE
ID  VALUE
1     8
2     9
3    11

RESULT after update with value max 10
ID  VALUE
1     8
2     9
3    10

UPDATE table
SET VALUE= FUNCTION(VALUE, 10)
WHERE id='62323';
```

Thanks

Comment: please post an example of starting data and what you need to obtain

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LEAST](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions099.htm#SQLRF00657):

```
UPDATE table
SET VALUE= LEAST(VALUE, 10)
WHERE id='62323';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using swich case

```
UPDATE table
SET VALUE = CASE WHEN VALUE >10 THEN 10 ELSE VALUE END WHERE id='62323';
```